# updaterate in libgazebo_ros_imu

Tags: ros, frequency

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I'm trying to simulate an IMU with the plugin libgazebo_ros_imu, but I have one problem. I've defined in my .urdf the following code:

```
  <gazebo>
    <controller:gazebo_ros_imu name="imu_controller" plugin="libgazebo_ros_imu.so">
      <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
      <updateRate>50.0</updateRate>
      <bodyName>imu_link</bodyName>
      <topicName>odom/imu</topicName>
      <gaussianNoise>2.89e-08</gaussianNoise>
      <xyzOffsets>0 0 0</xyzOffsets>
      <rpyOffsets>0 0 0</rpyOffsets>
      <interface:position name="imu_position"/>
    </controller:gazebo_ros_imu>
  </gazebo>
```

I set the frequency to 50 Hz, but when I do rostopic hz I get that the node is publishing at 1000 Hz (more or less). I've checked the plugin source code and I've seen that it gets all the params except the updateRate, so I think that thats the reason why I can't set the frequency I want.

I'm I right? And then, what can I do for changing the frequency?

I'm using Fuerte in Ubuntu 12.04

Thanks in advance. Regards!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40288/updaterate-in-libgazebo_ros_imu/) by [g.aterido](https://answers.ros.org/users/2783/g.aterido/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2012-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, the solution was use other plugin for the IMU. The IMU of hector_gazebo_plugins does not have this problem and works perfectly ;)

---

Originally posted by [g.aterido](https://answers.ros.org/users/2783/g.aterido/) with karma: 229 on 2012-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hbaqueiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/37094/hbaqueiro/) on 2018-11-21**:
Could you please share where did you find the source code of this libgazebo_ros plugin? I am facing the same problem but with the libgazebo_ros_projector. I suspect that inside it there is no call to some sdf tags such as the .